# Extend of a map of a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $G=\langle S\rangle$ be a finitely generated group and $\varphi:G\times X\to X$ be a continuous action of $G$ on metric space $(X, d)$. The map $F:G\to X$ is called $\delta$-pseudo orbit for $\varphi:G\times X\to X$, if $d(F(sg), \varphi(s, F(g))<\delta$ for all $s\in S$ and every $g\in G$. For example let $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}\times X\to X$ define by $\varphi(n, x)=f^n(x)$. Then $F:\mathbb{Z}\to X$ with $F(n)=x_n$, is $\delta$-pseudo orbit for $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}\times X\to X$ if $d(f(x_n), x_{n+1})=d(F(n+1), \varphi(1, F(n))<\delta$ and $d(f^{-1}(x_n), x_{n-1})d(F(n-1), \varphi(-1, F(n))<\delta$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

It is easy to see that if $\{x_n\}$ is $\delta$-pseudo orbit for $f^2:X\to X$, then $\{y_n\}$ define by
$y_{2n}=x_n, y_{2n+1}=f(x_n)$
is $\delta$-pseudo orbit for $f:X\to X$.

Note that $2\mathbb{Z}$ is finite index subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. Indeed
Subgroup $H=\langle A \rangle$ of $G=\langle S\rangle$ with $A\subseteq S$ is  finite index subgroup of $G$  if there is finite set $K\subseteq G$ with $G=KH$.

In my research $H$ is a finite index subgroup of $G$, I have a $\delta$-pseudo orbit $F:H\to X$ for $\varphi:H\times X\to X$ and I need to extend it to a $\delta$-pseudo orbit $F_1:G\to X$ of $\varphi:G\times X\to X$ such that $F(H)\subseteq F_1(G)$.

Would you please help me to know it.

Comment: Do you start with $\varphi : H \times X \to X$ or only $\varphi : G \times X \to X$?  If the former, then you are already out of luck:  the non-trivial action of $H = \mathrm C_2$ on $\mathrm C_3$ cannot be extended to an action of $G = \mathrm C_4$, in which $H$ has finite index, on $\mathrm C_3$.

Comment: Assuming you start with $\varphi : G \times X \to X$, do you want the same $\delta$ for $G$ as for $H$ or a different $\delta$?  If the same $\delta$, then you're out of luck:  consider $G = \mathrm C_4 = S$ containing $H = \mathrm C_2 = A$ as before, and let them act on $X = G$ by translation.  Define $$d(a, b) = \begin{cases} 0, & a = b \\ 1, & a = b + 2 \\ 10, & \text{otherwise,} \end{cases}$$ let $F$ be the inclusion $H \to G$, and let $\delta = 2$.  Then there is no extension of $F$ to a $\delta$-pseudoorbit of $G$.

Comment: But I suspect that you mean to change the $\delta$, because otherwise your example for $2\mathbb Z \subseteq \mathbb Z$ doesn't seem to work.  (In fact, with my $H$, $G$, $X$ as above, you can take $f$ to be the natural map $\mathbb Z \to G$.  Then $2\mathbb Z \to H$ is a $2$-pseudoorbit, but there is no $2$-pseudoorbit $\mathbb Z \to G$.

Comment: Sorry, missing parenthesis.)  […](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983499/extend-of-a-map-of-a-subgroup#comment8220639_3983499) Even if you allow $\delta$ to change, though, I don't see why your extension $\mathbb Z \to X$ works unless we have something like uniform continuity of $f$ (but maybe you meant this; $f$ is not actually introduced anywhere).

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for your reply. In my research, it is important to extend pseudo orbit $F_0:H\to X$ to pseudo orbit $F:G\to X$. In fact, I study a property $P$  of continuous action $\varphi:G\times X\to X$. And I want to know that if $\varphi:H\times X\to X$ has property of $P$, is it true that $\varphi:G\times X\to X$ has the property of $P$? In this way, I need to extend pseudo orbit $F_0:H\to X$ for $\varphi:H\times X\to X$ to a pseudo orbit $F:G\to X$ for $\varphi:G\times X\to X$.

Comment: Your [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983499/extend-of-a-map-of-a-subgroup#comment8220679_3983499) doesn't seem explicitly to answer my questions (they are about definitions, not motivation), but implicitly to suggest that you are taking $\varphi$ as given on all of $G$, not just on $H$; and that you are allowing $\delta$ to change as you extend the pseudoorbit.  Is that right?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, $f:X\to X$ is a homeomorphism. Also $\varphi:G\times X\to X$ is a continuous action of $G$ on compact metric space.

Comment: Even if $f : X \to X$ is a homeomorphism, it need not be uniformly continuous, so I still don't see why your extension works … except now you've [added](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983499/extend-of-a-map-of-a-subgroup#comment8220692_3983499) the condition that $X$ is *compact*.  If you mean this to be part of the question, then you should put it in the question.  Anyway, it still seems to me that, rather than answering my specific questions, you are answering other questions that I didn't ask.

Comment: @LSpice, Would you please help me   and introduce a reference to study it about my question?

Comment: @LSpice,Yes. We consider $X$ as a compact metric space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118414/discussion-between-user479859-and-lspice).